# scrapy ignoring response 404 but i want to skip this ignoring urls or fill it with null values

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy

I am scraping data from a newspaper using website URL but some of the URLs pages do not have the content for this reason my crawler is being stoped. my target is to continue the crawler, skip those pages or fill those pages content with NA values. here is my spider

```
import scrapy
from ..items import CollectDataItem
import logging


class JagonewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jagonews'
    page_number = 2
    source_url = 1
    start_urls = ['https://www.jagonews24.com/special-reports/news/1']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logger = logging.getLogger('scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror')
        logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        items = CollectDataItem()
        try:
            all_div_quotes = response.css('.marginBottom20 > .col-sm-12')
        except AttributeError:
            next_page = 'https://www.jagonews24.com/special-reports/news/' + str(JagonewsSpider.page_number)
            JagonewsSpider.page_number += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
        for quote in all_div_quotes:
            try:
                label = quote.css(".breadcrumb a::text").extract()
                title = quote.css('h1::text').extract()
                body = quote.css('p::text ').extract()
            except AttributeError:
                label = 'n/a'
                title = 'n/a'
                body = 'n/a'
            print(type(body))
            items['label'] = label
            items['title'] = title
            items['body'] = body
            items['source'] = 'https://www.jagonews24.com/special-reports/news/' + str(JagonewsSpider.source_url)
            yield items
            JagonewsSpider.source_url += 1
        next_page = 'https://www.jagonews24.com/special-reports/news/' + str(JagonewsSpider.page_number)
        print(next_page)
        if JagonewsSpider.page_number < 642548:
            JagonewsSpider.page_number += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

[image: This the error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this convenience approach.

```
   class JagonewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jagonews'
    page_number = 2
    source_url = 1
    start_urls = ['https://www.jagonews24.com/special-reports/news/{}'.format(x) for x in range(1,10)]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        if response.status != 404:
 
            print(response.status)
            print(response.url)
            # you can extract your item here.
```